# Cohomology of a family of twisted cubic curves (Hartshorne III, 12.9.2)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes, sheaf-cohomology

I'm trying to understand following Example in Hartshorne (Chapter III, Example 9.8.2
& Example 12.9.2):

Let $X_1 \subset \mathbb{P}^{3}$ be a twisted cubic curve not containing the point
$(0:...:1) $ (will become important when we project $X_0$ to $\mathbb{P}^{2}$)
and consider the automorphisms parametrized by
$\sigma_t, t \in k$ of $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ defined by $(x_0:...:x_3) \mapsto
(x_0:...:t \cdot x_3)$. Let $X_t:= \sigma_a(X_t)$. For $t \in k \neq 0$ all
$X_t$ are isomorphic as abstract schemes to $X_1$. Then the
$X_t$ form a flat family parametrized by $\mathbb{A}^1 - \{0\}$.

Now according to (9.8) this family extends uniquely to a flat family defined
over all of $\mathbb{A}^1$, and with $X_0$ happen crazy things.

Following Hartshorne it can be proved  (for details see book pages 259/260 )
that set theoretically $X_0$ coincides with
$X_1$ but as a scheme $X_0$ admits an embedded component $(0:0:0)$, in this case
it is a "double point" and the concern of this question is how does it effect
on cohomology.

Recall that the twisted cubic curve in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ was defined by the
parametric equations $x_0 = t^3 , x_1 = t^2 u, x_2 = tu^2 , x_3 = u^3$ . In other words,
it is just the $3$-uple embedding of $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ (Chap. II Example 7.8.5 and Chap I, Ex. 2.12).

Example 12.9.2 (page 289) contains some things about the cohomology of the members of the
family $X_a$ I not pretty understand. It says:

*Example 12.9.2.* In the flat family of (9.8.4), we have $h^0 (X_t, O_{X_i}) = 1$ if
$t \neq 0$, and $2$ if $t = 0$, because of the nilpotent elements. On the other
hand, $h^1 (X_t, O_{X_t}) = 0$ for $t \neq 0$, since $X$, is rational,
and $h^1 (X_t, O_{X_t}) =h^1 (X_t, O_{X_t})_{red})=1$
since $(X_0)_{red}$ is a plane cubic curve. So in this case the
functions $h^0 ,h^1$ both jump up at $t = 0$.

Several caclulations I not completly understand and would like to discuss:

I) on $h^0 (X_t, O_{X_t}) = 1$

Since $X_1 \cong X_t$ for $t \neq 0$ we can assume $t=1$. $X_1$ is a twisted cubic
curve of degree $3$ embedded by $3$-uple Veronese $\nu: \mathbb{P}^{1} \to \mathbb{P}^{3}$.
The first idea came up to me is to use the overkiller $X_1 \cong \mathbb{P}^{1}$ and to think only
about the cohomology of $\mathbb{P}^{1}$. I think that Hartshorne used at this point
another argument to reach $h^0 (X_t, O_{X_t}) = 1$, because looking at the used argument
for $h^1 (X_t, O_{X_t}) = 0$ where $t \neq 1$ he only used that $X_1$ is rational,
that is birational equivalent to $\mathbb{P}^{1}$, not neccessary isomorphic.
And indeed genus $g_1=h^1 (X_1, O_{X_1})$ is by Theorem 8.19 a birational invariant.

This leads me to suspicion that to establish $h^0 (X_1, O_{X_1}) = 1$
Hartshorne used another argument. Which one?
I'm looking for an argument using cohomology theory that for a rational, non singular irreducible
cubic curve  of degree $3$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ the space of global sections
has dimension one?

II) on $h^0 (X_0, O_{X_0}) = 2$

How the fact that $X_0$ is not reduced anymore rases the the dimension to $2$? More specificaly: the $X_0$ difers from $X_1$ by the observation the point $(0:0:0) \in X_0$ in an embedded point, $O_{X_0, (0:0:0)}$  has nilpotent elements. How to see formally that these contribute exactly an additional *one* dimension to the global sections:
that is $h^0 (X_0, O_{X_0})= h^0 (X_1, O_{X_1})+1$?

III) $h^1 (X_t, O_{X_0}) =h^1 (X_t, O_{X_t})_{red})$

Why passing from $X_0$ to associated reduced $(O_{X_0})_{red}$ not changes $h^1$?
(recall that the birationality argument not work anymore since $X_0$ isn't smooth.)

Comment: A smooth connected projective curve has no nontrivial functions. The question is not appropriate for this site, which is for research level questions.

Comment: To be fair, I have known plenty of research-level mathematicians who flinch at questions from Hartshorne's book.

Comment: @RP_: Certainly, but probably not at determining $H^0(C,\mathscr{O}_C)$ for a smooth projective curve $C$.

Comment: I have to admit that the first question is far from 
beeing a research one. I was desperate at that time, sorry. The answer
I meanwhile found is quite simple because $X_1$ is rational 
we can find two rational maps $X_1 \dashrightarrow P^1$ and
$P^1 \dashrightarrow X_1$ which can be uniquely extended to usual
morphisms since $X_1$ and $P^1$ are regular. As both maps have dense 
images the induced maps on global sections are injective, that is
we obtain a chain of inclusions

Comment: $k=H^0(P^1, O_{P^1}) \subset H^0(X_1, O_{X_1}) \subset
H^0(P^1, O_{P^1})$.  Thus $h^0(X_1, _{X_1})=1$ and I) is solved. I mean that this should be the shortest argument.

Comment: I made also some thoughts about II and III and whould be very
thankful if somebody could look through and tell me if my approach is ok.
We know that $(X_0)_{red}= X_1$ and $X_0$ is everywhere reduced exept in
$(0:0:0)$. That is $X_1$ can be considered as closed subscheme of $X_0$ and
the structure sheaves of $X_1$ and $X_0$ are related to each other 
by exact sequence

$$0 \to J \to O_{X_0} \to O_{(X_0)_{red}}=O_{X_1} \to 0$$ 
The ideal sheaf $J$ has support only at $(0:0:0)$ so it's support is 
zero dimensional and applying long cohomology sequence

Comment: to the sheaf
sequence above we conclude III) since $h^1(X_0, J)=0$. Only problem is
why $h^0(X_0, J) \cong J_{(0:0:0)}$ is *one-dimensional* $k$-space?